# Javascript: While Loop to Solve Exponents Problem Getting Error When Power Equals 0

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, exponent

I wrote javascript code to solve the following problem >>>

Write a function exponentiate that accepts two arguments:

- base (number)
- power (number)

Exponentiate should return the result of raising the base by the power. Assume the power argument will always be an integer greater than or equal to zero. Don't forget that any number raised to the 0th power is equal to 1!

```
function exponentiate (base, power) {

  if (power === 0){
    return result = 1
  }

  // while loop 
  let count = 0
  let result = 1;

  while (count < power){  

    result *= base
    count += 1
  }

  return result 
}


exponentiate(3, 0)
```

But I get the following error: ReferenceError: result is not defined

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is this an assignment ? I can see this same exercice a lot on repl.it : https://repl.it/@brynnact33/FSA-For-and-While-Loops-Prac-Probs-04-Exponentiate, https://repl.it/@Alicia33/Loops-and-Debugging-Workshop, ...

Comment: change `return result = 1` to `return 1;`

Comment: `var exponentiate = Math.pow;` I guess that's cheating.

Comment: @James lol seriously though if this isn't an assignment don't reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're accessing `result` before it is defined. so you should move them at the top of function
2. Here you should return value directly instead of assignment

   `if (power === 0){
       return result = 1
     }`

```js
function exponentiate (base, power) {
  let count = 0
  let result = 1;
  if (power === 0){
    return 1
  }

  // while loop 
  while (count < power){  

    result *= base
    count += 1
  }
  return result 
}

console.log(exponentiate(3, 0))
```

Simplest is using `**` [**exponent operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation)

```js
const exp = (b,e)=>{
  return b**e
}

console.log(exp(3,0))
console.log(exp(3,1))
console.log(exp(2,10))
```

Comment: Your point #2 is not actually a problem: `return result = 1` will return 1 anyway (of course, assigning a value to a variable which will never be used is not a good practice).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yeah, that's why i have written it you should do it like this, and also in OP's original code result was defined later than it is used.